# Bind python object to html button

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a python dictionary that creates a list of buttons, i.e.

```
recipes = {0 : {'name' : 'Chicken Ticka', 'products' : products_dict, 'instructions' : 'this are the instructions'},
                    1 : {'name' : 'Beef Masala', 'products' : products_dict_2, 'instructions' : 'this are the instructions for 2'}}
```

and in the HTML:

```
{% if recipes is not none%}
            {% for key, value in recipes.items() %}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-block">{{value['name']}}</button>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

And I want somehow to update(via refresh or dynamically) the page according to the button pressed.
 I know how to attach a button to a JS function, but how to attach that function with the corresponding object?

Comment: if i understand this correctly, you need to use ajax.

Comment: Your question is about a very basic concept of web development. You should educate yourself about HTML forms and how Flasks handles GET and POST requests with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly the method I had in mind, But I manged to get the functionality I desired:
The dictionary example:

```
products_dict = {0 : {'name' : '123', 'count' : '234'},1 : {'name' : '345', 'count' : '456'},2 : {'name' : '567', 'count' : '678'}}
    products_dict_2 = {0 : {'name' : 'bbb', 'count' : 'qwe'},1 : {'name' : 'wer', 'count' : 'ert'},2 : {'name' : 'rty', 'count' : 'tyu'}}
    recipes = {0 : {'name' : 'Chicken', 'products' : products_dict, 'instructions' : 'this are the instructions'},
                    1 : {'name' : 'Beef', 'products' : products_dict_2, 'instructions' : 'this are the instructions for 2'}}
```

The buttons creation:

```
            {% if recipes is not none%}
            {% for key, recipe in recipes.items() %}
            <button id={{key}} onclick="uploadRecipe({{recipe}})" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-block">{{recipe['name']}}</button>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

And the uploadRecipe function

```
<script>
    function uploadRecipe(recipe) {
        products = recipe['products'];
        var table = document.getElementById("recipeProducts").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        $("#recipeProducts tbody tr").remove();
        for (var prop in products) {
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = products[prop]['name'].bold();
            cell2.innerHTML = products[prop]['count'].bold();
        }
        document.getElementById("recipe_instructions_text").innerHTML = recipe['instructions'];
    }
</script>
```